# Does UIImage's imageNamed still cause memory issues on iOS4 for large images?

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I found a couple of Memory Management articles that mentioned `UIImage's imageNamed` causing problems when you have a lot of large images in memory.

http://akosma.com/2009/01/28/10-iphone-memory-management-tips/
http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

Both of these were written for OS version <= 3.0.

Does anyone know if these are still a problem in iOS 4?

Answer (score 3):

No longer a problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud), and [maybe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022371/iphone-sdk-does-3-0-clear-the-cache-of-a-imagenamed-because-2-2-1-doesnt).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at this link: [Dispelling the UIImage imageNamed: FUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud) you'll see there are really two problems with large images and imageNamed:

1. Prior to iOS 3.0 was a bug in the caching routines of imageNamed: such that it would not let go of its cache even when it received a mem warning.  This was a pretty major issue and was the source of a lot of memory crashes for me personally, as there's no way you could get memory back after using imageNamed: to load it.  This is NOT an issue anymore, as this seems to have been fixed in 3.0.
2. imageNamed: keeps, in its cache, the uncompressed image data itself.  For really large (in terms of their size on screen - width x height) images, this data can be really large.  width * height * 4 is what I've commonly seen cited for its uncompressed size.  This would still potentially be a problem for you if you are using rather large images - and is especially to be avoided if you don't need to redraw them often.

So to recap:  1 is no longer a problem, 2 might be.

Comment: This is because each pixel has four bytes: alpha, red, green, blue.  width * height gives you the number of pixels.

Answer (score 0):

it does.
In combination with UIPageViewController, definitely it does. 
trying to build a kids application displaying animal's sound and cartoon keyFrame animation
all individual animal details are in their own UIViewController
All views are displayed in UIPageViewController (Transition:scroll).
Didn't know about imageNamed bug and for nearly a month , thought it was a problem caused by UIPageViewController. Memory was never being released by ARC.
ASA i switched to imageWithContentsOfFile instead of imageNamed, all problems solved.
UIPageViewController was innocent in real. It works smooth now. No unreleased memory problem.