# Tableview scrolling is not so smooth?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a table view with three different custom cells.Each will be loaded from three different cell classes.`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"CellIdentifier";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell";
     static NSString *CellIdentifier3 = @"Cell";
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    { 
         CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
        }
        cell.datelabel.text=@"dhhg";
      cell.nameLabel.text=@"shdhsjdj";
    cell.msg.text=@"sdhhhfhjhfj";

       cell.myImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"sd.png"]; 
        cell.likelabel.text=@"hhhf";

        return cell;

    }
    else 
    {


        Customcellwithimage *cell = (Customcellwithimage *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[Customcellwithimage alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] autorelease];
        }
        cell.datelabel1.text=@"sdhkhks";
        cell.nameLabel1.text=@"sdhjkhkshd";
        cell.msg1.text=@"sdsdsd";

        cell.myImageView1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"shdjhjhs"]; 
        cell.likelabel1.text=@"sjdh";
        cell.bannerview1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"dshjs"]; 

        return cell;
    }

 return Nil;

}
```

` .This is my code for the design.Can anybody help me in where i am going wrong?

Comment: Does this even happen when you uncomment the image stuff?

Comment: it is loaded from my custom class.the cell itself contains one image.

Comment: Yes, so check if its still laggy when you uncomment all the code handling the image, so that finaliy no images are loaded. Basically, this should work and you have the proof that your images cause the laggs.

Comment: you use web image right?

Answer (score 1):

Your lag is probably caused because you are loading from disc in cellForRowAtIndexpath on the main thread. Try to avoid I/o operations on the main thread. Have a look here : [loading images from a background thread using blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502073/loading-images-from-a-background-thread-using-blocks/7502281#7502281)

Answer (score 0):

First of all cellIdentifier2 and cellIdentifier3 have the same value as @"cell". 
You have only included 2 conditions, one for section zero and second for others. 
You should also mention the condition for using cellIdentifier3.
You haven't mentioned what problem you are having because your code seems not to have any error. 
What output do you want? Different cells for different sections??

Comment: no.i want to load different cells for different types of responses i got from the webservise.as an expercience i have done this.

Comment: There might be the issue of loading images with larger resolution which might not be needed in the table view cell.                Therefore you can have smaller images in your server or in the project.                                                           But in case if you don't know the size of the image that you would receive then you can try resizing the image.

Answer (score 0):

Check your image size.
If image has big size, table view will not smooth

Comment: you should prepare your image to fit for your size of imageview.
before add to your project.
ex. 50x50 for normal display and 100x100 for retina display

Answer (score 0):

Your Code seems perfectly fine to me. Avoid using `[UIImage imageNamed:@"sd.png"]` because it used to create memory issues prior to ios 3.0 however with large images it may still create problems.

**You may read:**

[Does UIImage's imageNamed still cause memory issues on iOS4 for large images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389918/does-uiimages-imagenamed-still-cause-memory-issues-on-ios4-for-large-images)