# iPhone Dev: Animating PNG Sequences

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, oop, animation

What is the best or recommended technique for animating PNG Sequences.
**Heres what I've learned:**

**Do it Manually**
Using MutableArrays containing Strings, you can animate a UIImageView with a timer which increments an index number

**UIImage - animation methods**
This works, the only problem is to find if an image has completed its animation, you have to check the isAnimating BOOL, and to do that you need a timer.

**What is the best and recommended?**

*Looking to do Oldschool game sprite animations,*
ie:

Idle Animation
Attack Animation
Walk Animation
ect...


Let me know if any one has something.

@lessfame

Answer (score 12):

Example to animate arrows

```
    UIImage* img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fleche1.png"];
    UIImage* img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fleche2.png"];

    NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1,img2, nil];
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 160.0, 160.0)];
    [imageView setAnimationImages:images];
    [imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:100];
    [imageView setAnimationDuration:3.0];
    imageView.center = myView.center;


    [imageView startAnimating];
    [myView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use Core Animation layers to do sprite animation:

- Make a 'multi-cell' image strip (could be PNG or JPG) of all the various moves for the sprite. Make each 'cell' be a fixed height or width.
- Put the image in a UIImageView.
- Take the CALayer of the view, and adjust the `contentsRect` property of the layer. This acts as a clipping rectangle for the sprite. To animate sprite all you have to do is move the `contentsRect` over to the next cell position in the image strip.

Something like this will do it (assuming you've already calculated the newSpritePosition.

```
  [CATransaction begin];
  [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
  spriteLayer.contentsRect = newSpritePosition;
  [CATransaction commit];
```

(If you don't do the second line, then you'll get a default slide animation instead of a 'jump' to the next state.)

With this technique you can rotate through all the frames of the sprite -- much like a flipbook. CALAyer transactions are optimized so you should get pretty fast frame rates. You can set an `animationDidStop` completion handler to move to the next state of the sprite or loop back to the beginning frame.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are going to use the sprites.  If you just need a simple looping sprite then the UIImage method is great.  If you want more granular control then you will be happier loading the images into an array and cycling them using a `NSTimer` to handle the timing.  Personally I use the array method most often because it leaves me more options in the future (like detecting when animations have completed).  One more suggestion would be to check out the [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org) project.  Its sprite is alot more powerful than either of these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603315/frame-by-frame-animation/4650537#4650537), I found this to be a good way: [PNG Animation method by Moses DeJong](http://www.modejong.com/iPhone/#ex2)

From his words:

> This example implements an animation oriented view controller that simply waits to read the PNG image data for a frame until it is needed. Instead of alllocating many megabytes, this class run in about a half a meg of memory with about a 5-10% CPU utilization on a 2nd gen iPhone.

I'm still unsure exactly how it's done. I believe it basically uses UIImageView to cache up AVAudioPlayer.