# iOS frame by frame animation, by script

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, movie

There are a few SO questions regarding frame by frame animation (such as [frame by frame animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603315/frame-by-frame-animation) and other similar questions), however I feel mine is different so here goes.

This is partially a design question from someone with very little ios experience.

I'm not sure "frame by frame" is the correct description of what I want to do so let me describe that. Basically, I have a "script" of an animated movie and I'd like to play this script.
This script is a json file which describes a set of scenes. In each scene there are a few elements such as a background image, a list of actors with their positions and a background sound clip. Further, for each actor and background there's an image file that represents it. (it's a bit more complex - each actor has a "behavior" such as how it blinks, how he talks etc). So my job is to follow the given script referencing actors and background and with every frame, place the actors in their designated position, draw the correct background and play the sound file.
The movie may be paused, scrubbed forward or backward similar to youtube's movie player functionality.
Most of the questions I've seen which refer to frame-by-frame animation have different requirements than I do (I'll list some more requirements later). They usually suggest to use *animationImages* property of a *UIImageView*. This is fine for animating a button or a checkbox but they all assume there's a short and predefined set of images that need to be played.
If I were to go with animationImages I'd have to pre-create all the images up front and my pure guess is that it won't scale (think about 30fps for one minute, you get 60*30=1800 images. Plus the scrub and pause/play abilities seem challenging in this case).

So I'm looking for the right way to do this. My instinct, and I'm learning more as I go, is that there are probably three or four main ways to achieve this.

1. By using Core Animations and defining "keypoints" and animated transitions b/w those keypoints. For example if an actor needs to be at point A at time t1 and point B at time t2 then all I need to do it animate what's in between. I've done something similar in ActionScript in the past and it was nice but was particularly challenging to implement the scrub action and keep everytyhing in sync so I'm not a big fan of the approach. Imagine that you have to implement a pause in the middle of an animation or scrub to a middle of an animation. It's doable but not pleasant.
2. Set a timer for, say 30 times a second and on every tick consult the model (the model is the script json file along with the description of the actors and the backgrounds) and draw what needs to be drawn at this time. Use Quartz 2D's API and drawRect. This is probably the simple approach and but I don't have enough experience to tell how well it's going to work on different devices, probably CPU wise, it all depends on the amount of calculations I need to make on each tick and the amount of effort it takes ios to draw everything. I don't have a hunch.
3. Similar to 2, but use OpenGL to draw. I prefer 2 b/c the API is easier but perhaps resource wise OpenGL is more suitable.
4. Use a game framework such as [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) which I'd never used before but seems to be solving more or less similar problems. They seem to have a nice API so I'd be happy if I could find all my requirements answered by them.

Atop of the requirements I'd just described (play a movie given it's "script" file and a description of the actors, backgrounds and sounds), there's another set of requirements -

- The movie needs to be played in full screen mode or partial screen mode (where the rest of the screen is dedicated to other controls)
- I'm starting with the iphone by naturally an ipad should follow.
- I'd like to be able to create a thumbnail of this movie for local phone use (display it in a gallery in my application). The thumbnail may just be the first frame of the movie.
- I want to be able to "export" the result as a movie, something that could be easily uploaded to youtube or facebook.

So the big question here is whether any of the suggested 1-4 implementations I have in mind (or others you might suggest) can somehow export such a movie.
If all four fail on the movie export task then I have an alternative in mind. The alternative is to use a server which runs ffmpeg and which accept a bundle of all the movie images (I'd have to draw them in the phone and upload them to the sever by their sequence) and then the server would compile all the images with their soundtrack to a single movie.
Obviously to keep things simple I'd prefer to do this server-less, i.e. be able to export the movie from the iphone but if that's too much to ask then the last requirement would be to at least be able to export the set of all images (keyframes in the movie) so I can bundle them and upload to a server.

The length of the movie is supposed to be a one or two minutes.  I hope the question wasn't too long and that it's clear...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

well written question. for your video export needs check out AVFoundation (available as of iOS 4). If I were going to implement this, I'd try #1 or #4. I think #1 might be the quickest to just try out, but that's probably because I don't have any experience with cocos2d. I think you will be able to pause and scrub CoreAnimation: check out the CAMediaTiming protocol it adopts.

Comment: Thanks, AVFoundation is useful, been looking into it. The more general question of how to implement those sort of animations is still open for anyone else who wants to take a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

Ran, you do have a number of options. You are not going to find a "complete solution" but it will be possible to make use of existing libraries in order to skip a bunch of implementation and performance issues. You can of course try to build this whole thing in OpenGL, but my advice is that you go with another approach. What I suggest is that you render the entire "video" frame by frame on the device based on your json settings. That basically comes down to setting up your scene elements and then determining the positions of each element for times [0, 1, 2] where each number indicates a frame at some framerate (15, 20, or 24 FPS would be more than enough). First off, please have a look at my [library for non-trivial iOS animations](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/), in it you will find a class named AVOfflineComposition that does the "comp items and save to a file on disk" step. Obviously, this class does not do everything you need, but it is a good starting point for the basic logic of creating a comp of N elements and writing the results out to a video file. The point of creating a comp is that all of your code that reads settings and places objects at a specific spot in the comp can be run in an offline mode and the result you get at the end is a video file. Compare this to all the details involved with maintaining all theses elements in memory and then going forward more quickly or slowly depending on how quickly everything is running.

The next step will be to create 1 audio file that is the length that the "movie" of all the comped frames and have it include any sounds at specific times. This basically means mixing the audio at runtime and saving the results to an output file so that the results are easy to play with AVAudioPlayer. You can have a look at some very simple [PCM mixer code](http://www.modejong.com/iOS/#ex4) that I wrote for this type of thing. But, you might want to consider a more complete audio engine like [theamazingaudioengine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/).

Once you have an audio file and a movie file, these can be played together and kept in sync quite easily using the AVAnimatorMedia class. Take a look at this [AVSync](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVSync) example for source code that shows a tightly synced example of playing a video and showing a movie.

Your last requirement can be implemented with the AVAssetWriterConvertFromMaxvid class, it implements logic that will read a .mvid movie file and write it as a h.264 encoded video using the h.264 encoder hardware on the iPhone or iPad. With this code, you will not need to write a ffmpeg based server module. Also, that would not work anyway because it would take too long to upload all the uncompressed video to your server. You need to compress the video to h.264 before it can be uploaded or emailed from the app.