# loading a image from documents directory in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to load a image to UIImageView from my app documents library. I am trying to use the following code but it is not working.

```
UIImageView *background = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 10, 48, 36)] autorelease];

[background setImage:[[UIImage imageAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Thumbnail-small" ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"/Users/nbojja/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/60C2E4EC-2FE0-4579-9F86-08CCF078216D/Documents/eb43ac64-8807-4250-8349-4b1f5ddd7d0d/9286371c-564f-40b4-99bd-a2aceb00a6d3/9"]]] retain]];
```

can someone help me with doing this. thanks...

Comment: Why not just use imageNamed on UIImage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud) which has the code you want.

Answer (score 25):

If you *really* want to load an image from your app's documents folder, you could use this:

```
NSArray *sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *docDirectory = [sysPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Thumbnail-small.jpg", docDirectory];
background.image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath] autorelease];
```

However, as pointed out by others here, you probably want to load it from your app bundle, in which case either of these will work:

```
background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumbnail-small.jpg"];
```

or

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Thumbnail-small" ofType:@"jpg"];
background.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image.png",docPath];

BOOL fileExists=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];

if (!fileExists)
    NSLog(@"File Not Found");
else
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually need is:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myimagefile" ofType:@"png"]];
[self.testView.imgView setImage:img];
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
if let dirPath = paths.first {
let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("Image2.png")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path)
// Do whatever you want with the image
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"ThumbnailSmall.jpg"];`

This will load up what you want I think.