# How Does IB Load a UIImage: imagedNamed vs imageWithData?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nib

After reading the memory management for UIImage, I'm worried about how interface builder loads an UIImage. Does it use UIImage:imagedNamed or UIImage:imageWithData?

Comment: what exactly are your worries?

Answer (score 0):

See relevant [section](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/ImageSoundResources/ImageSoundResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH7-SW4) in "Resource Programming Guide":

> When you load a nib file that contains
>   references to image and sound
>   resources, the nib-loading code caches
>   resources whenever possible for easy
>   retrieval later. For example, after
>   loading a nib file, you can retrieve
>   an image associated with that nib file
>   using the imageNamed: method of either
>   NSImage or UIImage (depending on your
>   platform).

So it looks like it uses `imageNamed:` or some underlying internal routines.
**Edit:** You may also be interested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud/938332#938332) about `+imageNamed`

Comment: Whenever I hear "image caching" on the iPhone, I think of "`imageNamed:`".

Comment: exactly, it may use some similar private methods though, but technically it must be similar to imageNamed

Comment: I see, that's a trouble for me. I'm trying to avoid use imageNamed, since memory is very sensitive for my app. I have to load image in viewDidLoad, but that make IB not that useful for a layout tools as before.