# Can I set 2 images in the TableView Header?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 50)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"111-user.png"]];
[tableView setTableHeaderView:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

Can anybody tell me how  can i put the second image in setTableHeaderView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a UIView with your 2 UIImageViews and add the UIView to the tableHeaderView.

[EDIT]

Since you are still having problems I've done a quick test project so you can see how it works. You can download it from here http://bit.ly/fvJgiz

Comment: What's not working? @Jacob has posted the code for you to try, this should work as expected.

Comment: nothing was appearing on the Header of TableView may be its overriding the last UimageView..

Comment: @RAMAN RANA: SET the frame of the another image different from first one. otherewise its surely gonna override :)

Comment: Hey @Raman check out my updated answer for a test project. Hope this helps now :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `UIView` which will contain both `UIImageView` instances:

```
UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
UIImageView *firstImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 30, 50)];
[firstImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"111-user.png"]];
[headerView addSubview:firstImageView];
[imageView release];
//do same thing with another UIImageView...
[tableView setTableHeaderView:headerView];
[headerView release];
```

Comment: [UIImage imageNamed:@"111-user.png"] this is wrong method to hold a image in image view it store image in cache memory and it give memory waring if your project if big

Comment: @GhostRider, I beg your pardon?

Comment: [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DOT" ofType:@"png"]] always hold image in this formate that will not store in your phone cache memeory

Comment: @GhostRider, Why *wouldn't* the OP want this?

Comment: I actually think @GhostRider has got a point. I always had issues with imageNamed not freeing up memory allocated for images and read somewhere that pathForResource:ofType: is more efficient. Haven't done any tests to confirm it though.

Comment: Quick search and here's a code SO discussion on the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud

Comment: when you make a large size project then you got memory waring if you use this type [UIImage imageNamed:@"111-user.png"] so

Comment: @GhostRider Depends which OS version it is, but nevertheless you make a good point.

Comment: @RAMAN RANA :Thats what jacob has replied to.... please see the comment also which says do the same for image 2