# Load UIImages correctly? Memory Management with "Leaks"

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiimage

i´ve created a little game in which images are loaded when the user is touching the screen while moving. It depends on the screen position to load different images immediately. 
I´ve got an UIImageView and because within the "touchesMoved" function, i´m loading the different images like this:

```
 imageView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed: [photos objectAtIndex: newImage ] ] ;
```

Now i want to improve my memory management using Instruments with "Allocations" & "Memory Monitor". Here´s i´m setting different snapshots with "Mark Heap" points and look for leaks. The line above is highlighted and now i want to know what´s wrong with it.. How can i improve that image-loading (without caching)?

Answer (score 0):

Read this [Dispelling the UIImage imageNamed: FUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud)

and also read the links in the question as well. Should answer everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: imageNamed: does cache images.
If you're getting this line highlighted then there are 2 possible reasons (or both):

1. you're not properly releasing imageView
2. you're not properly releasing the photos array

Answer (score 0):

`+imageNamed` returns an autoreleased object, yet the `@property image` in UIImageView retains it through its use until overwritten. `-objectAtIndex:` must return an object with a retain count of 1 which is not released.

If that indeed is the problem then the fix is

```
imageView.image =  [UIImage imageNamed: [[photos objectAtIndex: newImage ] autorelease]];
```

However I doubt that is the real issue here.

Comment: bad solution. you have to find the real cause of the leak and no to fix it like this.