# appending string to file name by passing through variable in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsstring

```
NSString *devicetype;       

if((UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)){  
devicetype = @"ipad";  
}else{    
devicetype = @"iphone";  
}
```

---

I have two images

BACKGROUND_IPAD.PNG

AND

BACKGROUND_IPHONE.PNG

Now I want to use this string like

```
BackGround = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"background_%@.png",DEVICETYPE]];
```

Is this possible?
If not, then is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you an use it, but insread of that you can change the name of the image to the following

```
Image~ipad.png 
Image~iphone.png
```

Now when you load the image

```
//on the iPhone and iPad use the same image name
//image named will select the image automatically
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:"Image"];
```

It will automatically select the image basing on your current device

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works. I have tested and running successfully.

Comment: even if it does, using imagenamed is better

Comment: @Omar Abdelhafith [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623295/imagenamed-is-evil-how-to-use-the-function    -- The comment by Dark dust says to avoid using **imagenamed**. and also other ways would use more processing so I think better to use manual naming.

Comment: that was in older ios versions, for newer versions read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud