# iOS UITableViewController cells data filling

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4, xcode4

Two questions:

1. I am trying to build a app that has a table view. I would like the user to click on a topic and then the next table view has a image on the left and text on the right. Does anyone know any sample code that would help me accomplish this?

   Example:

   > iPad --> WiFi, and WiFi + 3G
   >   iPhone --> AT&T, Verizon
2. Also is their a way to tag images in xCode? So in my table view I can only pull images with tag "x"?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html for sample code on how to implement table views.

I don't understand your question about tagging. You can use [UIImage imageNamed:] to pull in images that are bundled in your app. Name them as you will.

See [Dispelling the UIImage imageNamed: FUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud) for a discussion of this method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make a navigation based app. This gives you an app with a view controller in place with a table view on the screen.

Take a look at these for more info:

[UITableViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCell)

In this last one take a look at `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`, this will allow you to use the style you need, if you have default and add a picture to this cell it will show in the left side, pushing the text a little to the right.

Answer (score 0):

For tagging an image you can simply do 

`image.tag = tagNumber;`

For the cell image you can have like this:

`image.tag = tagNumber;`

`cell.imageView.image = image;`