# Sprites and sharing UIImage between UIImageViews

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, sprite

I am considering using sprites for an image heavy game.

I'm trying to determine whether any extra memory is allocated when sharing a single UIImage between image views. I ran a test by creating 40 image views, once with a single image and once by creating 40 image instances and they appeared to use the same amount of memory.

If extra memory is allocated per image view using a single image, what's the use of using sprites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've just answered my own question. It appears the memory allocations for both tests are the same because I was using imageNamed: to load the images. And as noted here: [Dispelling the UIImage imageNamed: FUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924740/dispelling-the-uiimage-imagenamed-fud)

> With respect to the general behavior of the cache, it does cache based on filename (so two instances of +imageNamed: with the same name should result in references to the same cached data)

I reran the test using imageWithContentsOfFile: and found that no extra memory was allocated when sharing the same UIImage.

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, please mark your answer as accepted so that others might learn of your solution.  Cheers~

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out- I'm new to SO. I tried to it accept it, but it said I can't until tomorrow. Will do it then, though.