# Overriding initWithImage for an UIImageView inside a NIB

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uistoryboard

Here's the deal: I have twenty five view controllers in my storyboard, each one has a UIImageView that displays a PNG with a large file size.

It turns out that a UIImageView inside a nib will load their image using `[UIImageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:]]` method [(see the docs)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html). The problem with using `imageNamed:` is that when each view controllers is loaded, the image in its UIImageView is placed in the cache, and my app quickly starts getting memory warnings and crashes.

The way out is to use `[UIImageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]]`, which loads the image but doesn't cache it. So what I'm trying to do is use **in my NIB file** a subclass of UIImageView  that calls `imageWithContentsOfFile`. But I can't figure out how to grab the name of the image file that's set in the Attributes Inspector in Interface Builder.

#### UIImageViewNoCache.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImageViewNoCache : UIImageView
@end
```

#### UIImageViewNoCache.h

```
#import "UIImageViewNoCache.h"

@implementation UIImageViewNoCache

-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image{
   self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], theNameOfTheImageInTheNib];]
    }
}
@end
```

So, how can I get `theNameOfTheImageInTheNib`?

Comment: I don't think the image cache does what you think it does... Caching it, would REDUCE memory of the image across multiple uses

Comment: @JustinMeiners: Nope, it really increases memory size, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289360/problem-deallocing-memory-used-by-uiimageviews-with-fairly-large-image-in-an-ui

Comment: in that question I understand the problem was memory used by images is never being freed, not that the act of having the image cached made a copy or somehting

Comment: also you cannot get the name of the image, as the image, stores no information related to its name or filename, because they can be created in code etc, also if initWithImage is called wouldn't that image passed into the method already be in the cache?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this category I wrote: [UIImage+SDSCache](https://github.com/sdesimone/iOSSnippets/blob/master/SDSCategories/UIImage+SDSCache.m).

It swizzles `imageNamed` so not to use the cache. It could be useful to you as it is or as a sample of how to solve your specific issue.