# Memory is not released under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have an app with a parent View Controller. It has some buttons and when one of them is clicked it presents a Modal View Controller (using XIB). The code I use to present and dismiss the Modal VC is :

```
iPadViewController *iPadVC = [[iPadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:iPadVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

and to dismiss :

```
-(IBAction)Back:(id)sender{
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So the problem is, when I dismiss it, it does not release any memory. And if I present it 3/4 times it crashes. I am using ARC, never had similar problems because I tough that ARC did all the memory management job.
I do have some backgrounds that need a lot of space and they are not getting released either. I tried :

```
[backgroundImage removeFromSuperview];
backgroundImage=nil;
```

The memory does decrease using this code, I'm not sure if the image was released because the next time I press the button the memory increases to almost 300mb and terminates due to "memory pressure". If the VC was released it would work fine because it only uses 160mb on the iPad and 65mb on the iPhone. Also, My image is selected through the Xib utilities :

[image: IMG]

And I tried to use Xcode instruments and it does not show any leak (!) but it does show that the allocations are growing and growing every time I click a button.

[image: Allocations with Xcode Tools]

and on my ViewController.h:

```
IBOutlet UIImageView (...);
IBOutlet UIImageView (...);
IBOutlet UILabel (...);
IBOutlet UIButton (...);
IBOutlet NSTimer (...);
IBOutlet UIImage (...);
IBOutlet UIView (...);

-(IBAction)Back:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int ;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton ;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton ;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton ;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView ;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel ;
```

I tried to give all the details about my code, but if you need anything else just let me know, and thank you all so much!

Comment: "Xcode does not release memory" - surely, because Xcode is not the Objective-C runtime.

Comment: What is the error you get when your application crashed?

Comment: I have the error : "Terminated due to memory pressure"

Comment: in instruments you can see the call stack for each allocation--that will tell you where the memory is being allocated/retained.

Comment: yes as you can see in the image there are lots of images that are not being deallocated. I just don't understand why! I can't release them because it ARC won't let me, but it is not releasing them so is ARC useless? I don't think so because it always worked for me...except now.

Comment: Please, show the code where you instantiate `backgroundImage`

Comment: I don't use any code to do it. I just created an IBOutlet UIImageView. And then, on the XIB I dragged an UIImageView and selected the file "musicback.jpg" (like in the picture I uploaded).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Your images are big please see this question: [Problem dealloc'ing memory used by UIImageViews with fairly large image in an UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289360/problem-deallocing-memory-used-by-uiimageviews-with-fairly-large-image-in-an-ui)

To sum up: when using nib files all the assigned images are loaded using

```
[UIImage imageNamed]
```

method which is known to cause huge memory allocations because it always caches the images.
Try assigning the images to views in the code with

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

method (it is described in the answer to above question).

Comment: thank you! the thing is, I have an UIImageView, not a UIImage so I tried :  NSString *picture = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"musicback.jpg"];
    UIImage  *image    = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:picture];
    [backgroundImage setImage:image];
and it does not show any image...am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I managed to do it with  NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"musicback" ofType:@"jpg"];
    [backgroundImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName]]; but it still is not released from memory! Although, I added backgroundImage=nil to the dismiss method and it does get released! thank you! Now I just wanted to release the viewController completely...but thank you!

Comment: You need to add a slash to the path: [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/musicback.jpg"];

Comment: Seriously thank you so much! This was really giving me a big headache and no one was able to help me! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the modal view controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:Nil];
```

In the main View controller check it exists first before presenting it:

```
iPadViewController *iPadVC;

if (iPadVC == Nil)
 iPadVC = [[iPadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self presentViewController:iPadVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Sounds like iPadVC is always in scope so ARC may not be releasing it.