# Understanding the memory consumption on iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory-management, opengl-es

I am working on a 2D iPhone game using OpenGL ES and I keep hitting the 24 MB memory limit – my application keeps crashing with the error code 101. I tried real hard to find where the memory goes, but the numbers in Instruments are still much bigger than what I would expect.

I ran the application with the Memory Monitor, Object Alloc, Leaks and OpenGL ES instruments. When the application gets loaded, free physical memory drops from 37 MB to 23 MB, the Object Alloc settles around 7 MB, Leaks show two or three leaks a few bytes in size, the Gart Object Size is about 5 MB and Memory Monitor says the application takes up about 14 MB of real memory. I am perplexed as where did the memory go – when I dig into the Object Allocations, most of the memory is in the textures, exactly as I would expect. But both my own texture allocation counter and the Gart Object Size agree that the textures should take up somewhere around 5 MB.

I am not aware of allocating anything else that would be worth mentioning, and the Object Alloc agrees. Where does the memory go? (I would be glad to supply more details if this is not enough.)

---

*Update:* I really tried to find where I could allocate so much memory, but with no results. What  drives me wild is the difference between the Object Allocations (~7 MB) and real memory usage as shown by Memory Monitor (~14 MB). Even if there were huge leaks or huge chunks of memory I forget about, the *should still show up in the Object Allocations*, shouldn’t they?

I’ve already tried the [usual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281764/in-cocoatouch-iphone-os-how-do-i-findeliminate-leaks-that-the-instruments-leak) [suspects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289360/problem-deallocing-memory-used-by-uiimageviews-with-fairly-large-image-in-an-ui), ie. the `UIImage` with its caching, but that did not help. Is there a way to track memory usage “debugger-style”, line by line, watching each statement’s impact on memory usage?

---

*What I have found so far:*

1. I really *am* using that much memory. It is not easy to measure the real memory consumption, but after a lot of counting I think the memory consumption is really that high. My fault.
2. I found no easy way to measure the memory used. The Memory Monitor numbers are accurate (these are the numbers that really matter), but the Memory Monitor can’t tell you where exactly the memory goes. The Object Alloc tool is almost useless for tracking the real memory usage. When I create a texture, the allocated memory counter goes up for a while (reading the texture into the memory), then drops (passing the texture data to OpenGL, freeing). This is OK, but does not always happen – sometimes the memory usage stays high even after the texture has been passed on to OpenGL and freed from “my” memory. This means that the total amount of memory allocated as shown by the Object Alloc tool is smaller than the real total memory consumption, but bigger than the real consumption minus textures (`real – textures < object alloc < real`). Go figure.
3. I misread the Programming Guide. The memory limit of 24 MB applies to textures and surfaces, not the whole application. The actual red line lies a bit further, but I could not find any hard numbers. The consensus is that 25–30 MB is the ceiling.
4. When the system gets short on memory, it starts sending the memory warning. I have almost nothing to free, but other applications do release some memory back to the system, especially Safari (which seems to be caching the websites). When the free memory as shown in the Memory Monitor goes zero, the system starts killing.

I had to bite the bullet and rewrite some parts of the code to be more efficient on memory, but I am probably still pushing it. If I were to design another game, I would certainly think of some resource paging. With the current game it’s quite hard, because the thing is in motion all the time and loading the textures gets in the way, even if done in another thread. **I would be much interested in how other people solve this issue.**

Please note that these are just my views that do not have to be much accurate. If I find out something more to say on this topic, I will update the question. I’ll keep the question open in case somebody who understands the issue would care to answer, since these all are more workarounds and guesses than anything else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*I highly doubt this is a bug in Instruments.*

First, read this [blog post by Jeff Lamarche about openGL textures](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html):

- has a simple example of how to load
  textures without causing leaks
- gives understanding of how "small"
  images, get once they are loaded
  into openGL, actually use "a lot" of memory

Excerpt:

> Textures, even if they're made from
>   compressed images, use a lot of your
>   application's memory heap because they
>   have to be expanded in memory to be
>   used. Every pixel takes up four bytes,
>   so forgetting to release your texture
>   image data can really eat up your
>   memory quickly.

Second, it is possible to debug texture memory with Instruments.  There are two profiling configurations: [OpenGL ES Analyzer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/OpenGLESAnalyzer/OpenGLESAnalyzer.html) and [OpenGL ES Driver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/OpenGLESDriverInstrument/OpenGLESDriverInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011355-CH37-SW1).  You will need to run these on the device, as the simulator doesn't use OpenGL.  Simply choose Product->Profile from XCode and look for these profiles once Instruments launches.

---

Armed with that knowledge, here is what I would do:

- Check that you're not [leaking memory](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994) -- this will obviously cause this problem.
- Ensure your'e not [accessing autoreleased memory](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease) -- common cause of crashes.
- Create a separate test app and play with loading textures individually (and in combination) to find out what texture (or combination thereof) is causing the problem.

**UPDATE:** After thinking about your question, I've been reading [Apple's OpenGL ES Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/index.html) and it has very good information.  Highly recommended!

Comment: The link to the article is dead, any idea where I can find this information?

Comment: I added some info regarding what the article talked about.  I also removed the dead link.

Comment: I'm looking at the OpenGL ES Analyzer and OpenGL ES Driver configurations, and I cannot find the amount of used texture memory. How does one get the actual used OpenGL texture memory for an iOS app?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to start commenting out code and checking to see if the bug still happens. Yes it is tedious and elementary, but it might help if you knew where the bug was.

Where it is crashing is why it is crashing, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, I can’t simply comment out an allocation and hope the application does not notice.

Comment: Actually, this is not a bad advice. If the application consumes more and more memory, it IS possible to comment out portions of memory allocation code and narrow the potential suspects down to a single class or line.

Answer (score 2):

Hrmm, that's not many details, but if leaks doesn't show you where the leaks are, there are two important options:

[i] Leaks missed a leak
[ii] The memory isn't actually being leaked

fixing [i] is quite hard, but as Eric Albert said filing a bug report with Apple will help. [ii] means that the memory you're using is still accessible somewhere, but perhaps you've forgotten about it. Are any lists growing, without throwing out old entries? Are any buffers being realloc()ed a lot?

Comment: Any code encapsulated within the braces of a dispatch call to GCD is shielded from two things: error reporting and, sometimes, allocation counting. That usually only applies to CoreFoundation or any other thing non-UIKit or non-NSFoundation.

Answer (score 2):

For those seeing this after the year 2012:

The memory really loaded into device's physical memory is the Resident Memory in VM Tracker Instrument.

Allocation Instrument only marks the memory created by malloc/[NSObject alloc] and some framework buffer, for example, decompressed image bitmap is not included in Allocation Instrument but it always takes most of your memory.

Please Watch WWDC 2012 Session 242 iOS App Performance: Memory to get the information from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't specifically help you, but if you find that the memory tools don't provide all the data you need, please file a bug at bugreport.apple.com.  Attach a copy of your app and a description of how the tools are falling short of your analysis and Apple will see if they can improve the tools.  Thanks!