# Analyzing Instruments readings

Tags: instruments

**`Leaks:`**

```
None
```

**`ObjectAlloc:`**

```
Net Bytes: 4,332,512
# Net: 26,696
Overall Bytes: 103,769,552
# Overall: 738,987
```

**`Activity Monitor (MyApp):`**

```
# Thread: 6
Real Memory: 63.65 MB
Virtual Memory: 209.45 MB
```

Memory monitor showed same readings as Activity Monitor. I don't know whether these readings are good or bad. Memory indicated by Activity Monitor is horrifying. Should i be worried? Can i somehow estimate memory used by the application once its moved to the device. The real run time memory? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Memory usage as reported by Object Allocation is not very autoritative, at least according to my experience. The real deal is the real memory consumption as reported by Memory Monitor, see [my question on iPhone memory consumption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363493/understanding-the-memory-consumption-on-iphone). Your numbers seem to be measured in Simulator, such measurement is worthless. You have to measure on the device.

Comment: I've seen your post, and if memory monitor gives me the real reading, then i think i'm in trouble - but these readings are on simultor (i'm guessing that memory consumed on device will be same? or almost same). Any advise?

Comment: Thats a huge difference, am i missing something?

Comment: Measurings on the Simulator are in many cases completely off. You have to try on the device, there is no other way.

Answer (score 2):

Object Alloc is reporting to the total memory used over the entire lifespan of the run.  That means if objects are allocated and deallocated (which they often are) you see all the memory consumed in total.

Far more useful is to select the option "created and still living", then highlight regions of the graph where memory increases but it never goes down if you expect it would.  Then you can see how much memory is being allocated at that point and what is allocating it.  This works in the simulator as well as the device.

Comment: "Then you can see how much memory is being allocated at that point and what is allocating it."

How can i check what is allocating it. I can select the areas and graph shows me reading in bytes telling how much memory was consumed. And how much accurate is "created and still living".

Comment: The easiest way to see what is allocating what is switch to the tree view (one of the bottom icons) and disclose the elements for each memory block until you find what is consuming memory.

The "created and still living" is pretty accurate.