# How to profile memory usage & performance with Instruments?

Tags: xcode, performance, profiling, instruments, allocation

Of all the Instruments Trace Templates, I love using:

- Zombies to detect where an object is getting over-released, great for debugging `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` errors.
- Leaks to detect memory leaks.
- Core Animation w Color Blended Layers to detect frame rate & translucent subviews, great for smoothing up `UITableView` scrolling.

I always hear people saying to profile my app's memory usage & performance.

1. Why should I profile memory usage & performance? My app runs fine.
2. How do I do it?

I've used Allocations and see that my iPhone app starts at 1 MB total allocated memory and grows to 5 MB after normal usage. What is too high amount of memory usage on the iPhone? iPad? Mac?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

To answer the whys, profiling memory usage is especially important for iOS apps because iPhones and iPads have much less RAM than Macs. The iPhone 4 has 512 MB of RAM, but earlier versions had 256 or 128 MB. Factor in the RAM the OS uses and multitasking, and your app doesn't have much RAM to waste so it's important to be aware of how much memory your app uses.

Profiling performance is something you usually do when your app is running slowly. Profile it to find the slow spots in your code so you can make the code run faster. If your app runs fine, you don't have much need to profile for performance.

To answer the hows, use the Allocations instrument to measure memory usage. The Live Bytes column in the All Allocations category tells you the amount of memory your app is currently using. The Allocations instrument's heapshot analysis measures memory growth in your app. Use the menu on the left side of the jump bar to do heapshot analysis.

The Time Profiler instrument profiles your app for performance. The difficult part of using the Time Profiler instrument is interpreting the results. The Time Profiler instrument isn't going to tell you your app spends 75% of its time in Function X. You have to dig through the data to find the slow spots in your code.

Regarding acceptable memory usage, it depends on the devices you want to support and the app. An app like Xcode using 100 MB of RAM would be OK, but an app like TextEdit using 100 MB for a one page document would be a problem. 5 MB shouldn't be a problem for an iOS app.

Comment: Thank you for giving such a comprehensive answer! :)

Comment: I have found the Allocations instrument to be misleading when it comes to how much memory my app is really using.  It tends to give numbers far below the actual mem usage. The Memory Manager instrument will give you the actual amount of memory your app is using in the Real memory column.  I was developing an OpenGL game and was getting low memory warning left and right.  Allocations said I was only using 12M of RAM, Memory Manager said I was using 100M. So, there you go.

Comment: @Ian see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8797272/287403 It appears as though live bytes is more accurate, as the 'real memory' column in the memory tool continues to show blocks you long ago released and the OS hasn't reclaimed. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7574959/287403 in which I believe the overall bytes should line up closer to the 'real memory'

Comment: We're currently trying to get a handle on how many large images our app can display at one time.  After writing test app that just threw up large JPGs on a UIScrollView, using [UIImage imageNamed:] and/or [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:], we found that Allocations was showing only 5MB of usage right before the app would crash, whereas Real Memory Usage was showing about 750MB.  So for our purposes, in this case, Real Memory Usage was giving us more useful information.

Answer (score 7):

To address some of the comments in Mark's answer:

Allocations live bytes doesn't include OpenGL texture memory, which is used by CALayer/UIViews. This is the source of the disagreement with the Memory Monitor.

See the answer to this question here:
[Understanding the memory consumption on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363493/understanding-the-memory-consumption-on-iphone)

Answer (score 3):

The memory really loaded into device's physical memory is the `Resident Memory` in `VM Tracker Instrument`.

`Allocation Instrument` only marks the memory created by `malloc/[NSObject alloc]` and some framework buffer, for example, decompressed image bitmap is not included in `Allocation Instrument` but it always takes most of your memory.

Please Watch WWDC 2012 Session 242 iOS App Performance: Memory to get the information from Apple.