# iPhone framework to measure performance

Tags: iphone, performance, frameworks

Is there any iPhone framework that help us keep track of the performance of each of the methods used when navigating throughout an iPhone application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4: How to profile memory usage & performance with Instruments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641540/xcode-4-how-to-profile-memory-usage-performance-with-instruments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already something similar discussed in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641540/xcode-4-how-to-profile-memory-usage-performance-with-instruments)

you can find more about performance tools on the apple developer website:
[ios reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001410-CH205-BCIIHAAJ)

hope that this is what you were asking for..

Answer (score 2):

There is no framework but a tool "Instrument" where you can trace lot of things including your app performance. Click here [How to profile memory usage & performance with Instruments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641540/xcode-4-how-to-profile-memory-usage-performance-with-instruments).

Hope i get you right and this may help you.