# ARC Memory Management: random memory warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I keep getting random crashes saying:

*Received memory warning.
(lldb)*

Now after a bit of reading I have found that this is probably due to memory management, resources been fully used and none free. I thought in ARC we dont need to free up memory and release things (it wont even let us release) I thought it did it all by itself.

I have seen from some articles & threads that a possible problem is way that you define `@properties` so some I have:

**FirstViewController**

```
@property (strong) FilterViewController *filterViewController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *sliderValue;

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *passedData;

@property int selectedTime;
```

**FilterViewController**

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *stepperValueLabel;
@property (strong) FirstViewController *firstViewController;
```

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641540/xcode-4-how-to-profile-memory-usage-performance-with-instruments) for information on how to profile memory usage.

Comment: @trojanfoe my question was how do I free up memory in ARC

Comment: You assign the object reference to `nil` when you are not using it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `Retain cycle.`  firstViewController object is retains filterViewController, and filterViewController object is retains firstViewController

```
@property (strong) FirstViewController *firstViewController; in FilterViewController 
@property (strong) FilterViewController *filterViewController; in FirstViewController
```