# How to check the size of a message sent

Tags: ios, objective-c, instruments

Is there any way to check the size of a message that is executed in your code? And how to get to it?

I have 3 textFields and delegated them, and used protocol

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self.toTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.subjectTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.bodyTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

I want to see the size (RAM) that is taken up, by me clicking the return key on one of the keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Instruments to check the memory usage.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641540/xcode-4-how-to-profile-memory-usage-performance-with-instruments).