# OpenGL memory management

Tags: ios, memory-management, buffer, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I have created an iOS application where I use GLKViews to realise an OpenGL environment. Now that everything works as expected, I have noticed that I get huge memory allocations and memory warnings as soon as I reinstantiate the view about three times over. Upon initialization I load textures like this:

```
  NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                              GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                              nil];

    NSError *error;
    topTexture = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:[self imageWithView:v].CGImage options:options error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error loading texture from image: %@",error);
    }
```

and delete them (and the buffers) when the GLKView will disappear like this:

```
-(void)cleanUp{

    if(vertexArray != 0){
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexArray);
        vertexArray = 0;
    }

    if( texArray != 0){
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &texArray);
        texArray = 0;
    }

    GLuint fT = frontTexture.name;
    glDeleteTextures(1, &fT);

    GLuint lT = leftTexture.name;
    glDeleteTextures(1, &lT);

    GLuint rT = rightTexture.name;
    glDeleteTextures(1, &rT);

    GLuint baT = backTexture.name;
    glDeleteTextures(1, &baT);

    GLuint boT = bottomTexture.name;
    glDeleteTextures(1, &boT);

    GLuint tT = topTexture.name;
    glDeleteTextures(1, &tT);

}
```

This is how they get drawn:

```
-(void)draw{


    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    self.effect.texture2d0.enabled = YES;

    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){

        if(i==0)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, frontTexture.name);
        if(i==1)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, rightTexture.name);
        if(i==2)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, backTexture.name);
        if(i==3)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, leftTexture.name);
        if(i==4)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bottomTexture.name);
        if(i==5)glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, topTexture.name);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, i*6, 6);
    }



}
```

Still, when I watch the allocations the live bytes go up 2 MB upon instantiation. Then when I remove the view the live bytes remain the same. So it seems the 2MB that are created are never released.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are testing this with ObjectAlloc, I don't think ObjectAlloc will see the OpenGLES related memory, Memory Monitor is more appropriate for this test.

Besides, there is no guaranty that the memory will be freed at the moment you call glDeleteTextures. The driver could defer this later.

You should use glFinish to make your test more accurate.

See zoul's post for more details : [Understanding the memory consumption on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363493/understanding-the-memory-consumption-on-iphone)